# Python IndexError: too many indices for array when trying to append two csv files

Tags: python

I keep getting this error whenever I try to append two csv files together.

```
log1 = np.genfromtxt('log40a.csv', dtype = float, delimiter=',', skip_header =1)
log2 = np.genfromtxt('log40b.csv', dtype = float, delimiter=',', skip_header= 1)
data = np.append(log1, log2)
```

This is the line the error I get on.

```
mSec = data[:,0]
```

It works fine if I don't append both csv and I just plot the log1 file, but when I try to append them for some reason I the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-5-6155c8de61ad>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/myname/.spyder2-py3/setdataexp.py', wdir='C:/Users/Myname/.spyder2-py3')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 89, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/Myname/.spyder2-py3/setdataexp.py", line 11, in <module>
    mSec = data[:,0]

IndexError: too many indices for array
```

EDIT: I forgot to add a sample of the csv file

```
mSec,speed,heading,gspeed,....
20,3.5,3,4.5
21,3,4,5
22,3.5,6,5.5
```

Comment: Try `mSec = [ x[0] for x in data ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the python documetation and you are using numpay you need to check this method for fusing existing arrays  `numpy.concatenate`
Ex taked from the docs:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> b = np.array([[5, 6]])
>>> np.concatenate((a, b), axis=0)
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])
```

[Documetation of numpay](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

And you have more methods to fusion your array:

- [np.hstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html)
- [np.vstack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)
- [np.column_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html)
- [np.row_stack](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.row_stack.html)

Comment: I get this error. AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'extend'

Comment: Remaked the answer check it.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `,0` and everything will work fine.

```
mSec = data[:]
```

This traceback

```
  File "C:/Users/Myname/.spyder2-py3/setdataexp.py", line 11, in <module>
    mSec = data[:,0]
```

said that it is a problem in your code.

**UPD:**

`np.append` produce single dimensional array and it doesn't allow slicing operations, you have to modify append operation like this:

```
data = np.append(log1, log2, axis=0)
```

Comment: How will it know what to assign to mSec because I have more than one column in the code. For example, I also have speed= data[:,1]

Comment: Thanks that worked. I tried to add a 3rd log3, I am guessing append only takes 2 arguments? do I need to just append data with log3? or is there a better way?

Comment: @J.Jones you can vote Gatusko answer, he had mentioned http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html which do what you have described.